# Calculation of AES encryption per second

Tags: aes

How fast in terms of the number  AES encryption/sec, would an Internet encryptor need to be if the plain text rate is 10gb/sec?

Comment: between 78,125,000 and 83,886,080 depending on how Gb is defined, better round up to 84 million

Comment: This will heavily depend on the [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) you use with your AES encryptor, as well as the size of the data you wish to encrypt. Could you provide more information on that regard? For instance on my standard laptop computer, thanks to the AES-NI instructions I can encrypt data of  8192 bytes at a rate of 331GB/s (!!) using aes-128-ccm, and it goes down to 807MB/s using aes-256-cbc... So YMMV a lot depending on those settings.

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume a few things:

1. 10 gb/sec means Gb/s, the number of gigabits per second;
2. we use network notation for Gb/s, which means that 1 Gb consists of 1,000,000,000 bits;
3. we'll use the minimum of AES blocks to encrypt - this is true for most single pass modes of encryption such as CBC and CTR;
4. we only use the AES primitive for confidentiality, not message integrity or authenticity (this restriction is lifted in the second part of the answer).

In that case 10 Gb/s is 1.250 GB/s. And as AES encrypts 16 bytes per block, this comes down to 78,125,000 operations per second (ops/s). Depending on the protocol and mode a few operations may be required at the start or end but those are insignificant to the ~78M ops/s.

---

If AES is *also* used for message authentication, for instance using AES-CMAC then you should double the amount of ops required.

Authenticated encryption modes based (solely) on AES such as CCM mode and EAX mode are "double pass", which means that two AES block encrypts are required for each block of input.

AES-GCM uses 128 bit modular multiplication during GMAC calculation. It is likely faster than these double pass modes, especially on newer processors with instructions to accelerate the multiplication required for GCM.

Comment: 'If AES is also used for message authentication'; actually, if you're using GCM, than you don't need to double the amount of ops; you will do one additional AES operation per encrypted block, but that's it...

Comment: this depends on what it means to be fast as well. such as cycles to load, store, or send? as well as possible guard intervals for the transmission.

Comment: @user3201068 The amount of AES operations per second was requested in the question. Of course, with GCM using not just using AES block encrypt, this gets warped a bit, as 128 bit modular exponentiation is *relatively* lightweight operation, but it is certainly not something you leave out when estimating performance.

Comment: Interestingly and empirically, for what it is worth: running `openssl speed -elapsed -evp aes-128-ccm` vs `openssl speed -elapsed -evp aes-128-gcm` brings CCM to the top, with two orders of magnitude of difference (!). I bet this is because it can rely more on the AES-NI instructions on my current CPU.